# Splitting and extracting values from a row?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

From the following line, I want to extract the date and time including AM/PM.
But the time part of DateTime is skipped.

```
 6/1/2018 12:01:11.490 AM   HEP.U02.OIL.GOV.P2_RUN  <Unit #2>No.2 oil pump runing   On    "

p=[]
xx = "6/1/2018 12:01:11.490 AM  HEP.U02.OIL.GOV.P2_RUN  <Unit #2>No.2 
oil pump runing On  "
new=re.split(r'\s',xx)
print(new)
p.append(new.pop(0))
p.append(new.pop(1))
print(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `time` part is there, `pop` function is the problem, your regex is fine, as can be seen by running source code below (there is no need for `pop` in this case tbh):

### Simple solution (without `pop`):

```
import re

xx = (
    "6/1/2018 12:01:11.490 AM  HEP.U02.OIL.GOV.P2_RUN  <Unit #2>No.2 oil pump runing On"
)
new = re.split(r"\s", xx)
print(new[:3])
```

Which returns as expected:

```
['6/1/2018', '12:01:11.490', 'AM']
```

### Why it didn't work?

When you `pop` element it is removed from the list. You remove `0` element (`'6/1/2018'`), new `0` element became the missing date and afterwards you popped **first element** which is actually `AM`.

With popping you would do that to get all three (assumming `new` is already created as before):

```
for _ in range(3):
    print(new.pop(0))
```

Comment: isn't there any other way I can retrieve those values without poping?

Comment: Of course there is,updated my answer. It would work with `pop` as well, though it's totally not needed here IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I am not great at regex and there is certainly scope to tighten this regex up but as a first stab assuming your datetime strings have a fixed format. It does not validate the date.

```
import re

xx = "6/1/2018 12:01:11.490 AM  HEP.U02.OIL.GOV.P2_RUN  <Unit #2>No.2 oil pump runing On  "

p1 = re.compile('(?:\d{1,2}\/){2}\d{4}\s+(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\.\d{3}\s+[AaPp][Mm]')
p = re.findall(p1, xx)
print(p)
```

Comment: You missed the actual problem with his code and created highly complex regex which does not work any better (only clutters the whole thing and makes it much less readable/understandable by others).